# Including additional data in Django DRF serializer response that doesn't need to be repeated every entry?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-gis

Our Django project sends GeoFeatureModelSerializer responses and we want to include an additional value in this response for JS to access. We figured out how to do this in serializers.py:

```py
from rest_framework_gis import serializers as gis_serializers
from rest_framework import serializers as rest_serializers
from core.models import Tablename

class MarkerSerializer(gis_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    new_value = rest_serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_new_value')

    def get_new_value(self, foo): return True

    class Meta:
        fields = ("date", "new_value")
        geo_field = "geom"
        model = Tablename
```

JS can get this value with `geojson.features[0].properties.new_value` where `const geojson = await response.json()`, but it's unnecessarily added with every entry. We'd like for it to be included only once so JS can access it with something like `newResponse.new_value` and existing functionality can continue getting the same data via `newResponse.geojson` or similar.

How can we include a single additional value in this response? We thought maybe [wrapping our serializer in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326819/wrap-a-django-serializer-in-another-serializer), but they seem to be asking a different thing we don't understand. Can we append this somehow? In the serializer can we do something like `newResponse = {'new_value': new_value, 'geojson': geojson}` somewhere?

We've had a dig through [the Django Rest Framework serializers docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) and couldn't work it out, so perhaps we're missing something. Other [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38758962) seem to only ask about adding data for every entry.

edit: we should have mentioned we're using viewsets.py, which looks like:

```py
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    bbox_filter_field = "location"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Marker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76134553) is if you're using views, but for viewsets see [`list()`](https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.viewsets/ReadOnlyModelViewSet.html#list) and include this in your viewset:

```py
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

    # idk what this code does but as we're overriding probably best to keep it
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset) 
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    # adjust things as desired here like so, defining self.new_value elsewhere
    returned_object = {'new_value': self.new_value, 'geojson': serializer.data} 
    
    return Response(returned_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to handle in View, not in serializer.

```
geojson = MarkerSerializer(queryset, many=True)
response = {
  "new_value": new_value,
  "geojson": geojson
}
return Response(response)
```

If you need to handle in serializer still, you need to create another custom serializer.

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
   new_value = SerializerMethodField()
   geojson = MarkerSerializer(many=True)


# view.py
serializer = CustomSerializer({"geojson": queryset})
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work perfectly in views.py but we should have explained we use this in viewsets.py (see edited question). Know how we could apply this approach in viewsets.py? We looked to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55147701) but don't know how to get `retrieve()` to work.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions
You need to check this docs. According to your example, `retrieve`function is matched with `GET /{route}/{id}/`.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter This docs shows actions, routes together

Answer (score -1):

You can use get_foo() for custom fields with SerializerMethodField.

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField
...

class MarkerSerializer(gis_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    new_value = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_new_value(self):
        return True

    class Meta:
        fields = ("date", "new_value")
        geo_field = "geom"
        model = Tablename
```